# How can I handle null cases for GSON in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

I am beginning to transition from Java to Kotlin. I have the following data class:

```java
data class NetworkResponse constructor(val title: String)
```

This class will be later used by `GSON` to convert a JSON file to an object of this class. but there are chances that `title` may receive a `null`.

In Java this wasn't a problem at the time of transformation from JSON to object (but since I am not using the `?` notation with string, it could be), but this is definitely a problem when storing data data in the `Room` db because there I don't want to add null values and I am using this same class as `@Entity`.

In Java, I used to makeadd logic of converting null to Some value (like say, uuid) in setters, but here I can not do such thing because the constructors do not have a body and I have to use the `init` which would mean that I have to declare my variables outside constructor which is also not a case for `data` class. What can I do such that:

1. I still have a `data` class
2. I have all my variables in the constructor only
3. I have all my variables of type `T` only , and not `T?`(i.e., non nullable)
4. when converting the JSONString to Response class's object, I can create a unique instance even for nullable data (like if I am getting a variable `id` as null, I am still able to create an instance and a logic should run that `if value==null, return <results from my logic for creating a random id>`
5. I should have more control over defining the logic of conversion stated in point 4 (for example, if `id` receives `null`, I can use a complex logic for generating a unique id, but if say `img_url` receives `null`, I can simply store it as `"no data"` (i.e., multiple logic for different type of null conversion))
6. I would prefer if this problem is solved via Kotlin and not via third-party hacks from `Gson` or `Room`

Comment: If you create table with NOT NULL DEFAULT “” it won’t be nullable anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there's a chance you will get null on one of the response parameter types, you must choose one of the following options:

1. Change type to nullable, so:

   `data class NetworkResponse constructor(val title: String?)`
2. Set a default value for the parameter, like so:

   `data class NetworkResponse constructor(val title: String = "")`

If you want to use more advanced logic if this value is null, you can also register a `JsonDeserializer` and write the logic to convert the null/empty value to whatever you like there:

`GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(type, MyCustomJsonDeserializer())`